# Getting facet grid plot out of Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

So I have a dataframe that looks like: (1st col is just index)

```html
CCS_Category_ICD9 Gender Admit_Month count
0 1 M 9 1
1 2 F 1 5
2 2 F 3 1
3 2 F 4 1
4 2 F 5 2
5 2 F 8 3
6 2 F 9 1
7 2 F 10 1
8 2 F 11 3
9 2 F 12 5
10 2 M 2 2
11 2 M 4 1
12 2 M 5 4
13 2 M 7 2
14 2 M 8 11
15 2 M 11 2
16 2 M 12 1
17 3 F 9 1
18 3 M 8 1
19 3 M 11 1
20 4 F 1 8
21 4 F 2 10
22 4 F 3 6
23 4 F 4 10
24 4 F 5 35
25 4 F 6 13
26 4 F 7 10
27 4 F 8 23
28 4 F 9 12
29 4 F 10 13
... ... ... ... ...
4758 2620 M 7 7
```

I have been trying to get a plot by ccs code and the count of by admit_month and gender using seaborn

This sort of gets in the right direction:

```
g = sns.factorplot(x="Admit_Month", y="count", column='CCS_Category_ICD9',data=ngrpdf)
```

[image: Admit by month]

But what I really want is a full set of charts one per ccs_category with the admit month as the bottom axis and bars indicating the counts by gender for the month

So I was trying something like:

```
g = sns.FacetGrid(ngrpdf, col='CCS_Category_ICD9',hue='CCS_Category_ICD9', col_wrap=4)
g.map(sns.factorplot(x="Admit_Month", y="count"))
```

Which just blows up, and nothing seems to get me bars by gender..
Been messing around sadly for a while with no luck. any guidance appreciated...

Comment: I think you want `col=` rather than `column=` in that first line of code.

Comment: That sure did not do it! it flattened the graph into one multi coloured thin line! The second code block at least does one blank chart for each ccs code...

Comment: Well, it looks like you might have 2620 `CCS_Category_ICD9` levels, so it's going to be hard to plot those all as facets. But that's what it did.

Comment: Well the numbers are not consecutive so there are about 200 or so,, but the bigger point was that I was trying to get one plot per ccs code (in the second code block) eg 200 or so plots (bar) with the counts by gender and month of encounter...??

Comment: Even 200 columns is too many.

Comment: Ok, What about the second code block? where I'm trying to plot each ccs separately? (which is really what I'm after) I only included the 1st since it vaguely looked like what I'm trying to do for each one of the ccs codes separately?

Comment: I'd suggest you take a look at the FacetGrid [examples](http://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/generated/seaborn.FacetGrid.html), but you're going to have the same problem of trying to make a plot with 200 columns...

Comment: The second block of code renders all plots in a good layout but says it cannot interpeter "Admit_Month" The x+  ?? If I add data=ngrpdf after the y= argument, as the data source in the second line it says Facetgrid is not callable...

Comment: Ahh This approximates what I'm looking for... needs a bit more fine tuning..  g = sns.FacetGrid(ngrpdf, col='CCS_Category_ICD9',hue='Gender', col_wrap=4)
g= g.map(plt.scatter,"Admit_Month","count")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With many thanks to @mwaskom for the great work and pointer to read the facet grid doc more carefully, this is what I came up with:

```
pal= dict(M='blue',F='red')
g = sns.FacetGrid(ngrpdf, col='CCS_Category_ICD9',hue='Gender', palette=pal,hue_order=['M','F'], col_wrap=4)
g = (g.map(plt.scatter,"Admit_Month","count").add_legend())
```

Which works like a charm even with a 1 million record dataset and some 200+ ccs categories:

An except from the charts looks like:

[image]